# Reuse procedure that references datatable in For Loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I am trying to reuse a procedure that creates a button for each item on my database.  I use the exact same procedure about 6 different times in my program, so I want to find a way that I can just write it once and reuse.

My question is, since I will be using different datatables and table adapters, how can I parametize those 2?

I have figure out the rest of my parameters: buttons and labels and forms.  Here is my code

```
Public Sub addCategories()

    'Procedure creates a button for each category
    'stored in the database and adds them to the
    'main panel

    Dim ta As New ContactsAndInventoryDataSetTableAdapters.PRODUCT_CATEGORYTableAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable = ta.GetData


    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Dim btn As New btnCategoryTabs()

        btn.lblCategoryName.Name = DirectCast(row("Category_Name"), String)
        btn.lblCategoryName.Text = btn.lblCategoryName.Name
        btn.lblCategoryID.Text = CStr(row("Category_ID"))

        Using STREAM As New MemoryStream(DirectCast(row("image"), Byte()))
            btn.picPCategoryPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(STREAM)
        End Using

        'Add categories to the Panel
        frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.Add(btn)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I would look into using generics.

Comment: Find all variable elements within your sub and move them to parameters. For example, `"Category_Name"` can be `string` parameter, and your data table will be another.